# malloc pointer identification

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

So I have this assignment to implement my own malloc and free in C. The problem is one of the requirements for the `memory_free(void *ptr)` function. It has to return 1 if the pointer is invalid, i.e. it hasn't been allocated by the `memory_alloc(unsigned int size)`, or return 0 otherwise. I just can't figure out a way to do this, without it being absolutely time inefficient.

So my memory structure is this: I have a global pointer to the beginning of the array I get to act as a heap. Every block of memory has an `int` header to tell the size of it and whether it's free or not.

This is my memory_free(void *ptr) function right now, TYPE is `typedef unsigned int`:

```
int memory_free(void *ptr)
{
    void *head = ptr;
    if (head == NULL)
        return 1;
    head -= sizeof(TYPE);
    if (!((*(TYPE*) head) & 1 ))
        return 1;
    (*(TYPE*) head) &= ~0x1;
    return 0;
}
```

The pointer `ptr` points to the first byte of user block, which means that if I want to read the header, I have to go back 4 bytes. One solution to check the validity of the pointer is to go through the heap from the beginning and see if I get on the header in question, but that's not time efficient. Could anyone tell me a better way?

Comment: How exactly is this code inefficient? It looks quite efficient to me. The main concern is rather that the code looks completely unsafe. I wouldn't implement a dynamic memory allocation algorithm without some kind of lookup table keeping track of what chunks of memory that actually exist. What if the pointer points at random garbage? What if the user calls memory_free twice on the same object by mistake?

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I have to test against that whenever memory_free is called. And that's my question :). Just to be clear, I'm basically not checking  it now, because those conditions there are successful half the time.

Comment: If so, how do you expect anyone to be able to answer without providing info about how you allocate and keep track of memory?

Comment: I'm afraid any valid solution requires some waste of memory (keeping some status information in every block's header) and time (verifying the consistency of the header with the rest of allocator's data) or a big waste of memory (eg. a separate list or hash table of all allocated blocks)...

Comment: The requirement to validate the pointer when freeing really complicates an implementation and there is a good reason that `free` results in UB in such cases, instead of complaining about the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

One O(1) solution would be to make the header 8 bytes instead of four; use the extra four bytes to indicate validity. For example, it could be the one's complement of what you store in the other four bytes. So you look at the header and if those extra bytes contain anything other than the one's complement of the  first part of the header, you know it's not a valid block.

Comment: This approach seems to have a flaw: imagine calling `ptr = memory_alloc(64)`, then user code writing to that area, then calling `memory_free(ptr + 32)`. This way the allocator can be "tricked" to think otherwise.

Comment: Well, sure. Most mallocs can be very easily "tricked" this way.

Comment: `free` doesn't have to check the validity of its argument; passing a pointer that was not returned by `(m|c|re)alloc` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is an O(1) approach, but terribly wasted memory space. My malloc has to be able to accomodate as little memories as 100 bytes, and extra 4 bytes to each block is huge. But thanks, good idea.

Comment: @Slaaavo: if you are so sensitive about the size of the bookkeeping, you should look at having a bitvector whose bits indicate whether the slots in a particular range are free or occuppied. Keep in mind that this works only for objects of a fixed size in a given range. I have implemented such "bitslots" in my slab allocator: https://github.com/bbu/userland-slab-allocator

Comment: You've got the problem that the result of malloc must be correctly aligned for any purposes. Typically malloc has a 16 byte alignment, to accommodate storing vectors in a malloc block, so you are practically forced to add 16 bytes. Unless of course you write your own malloc, for example allocating one big block for all mallocs up to 16 bytes, another big block for all mallocs up to 32 bytes etc.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 possible alternatives:

- Keep a linked list of pointers that you have allocated : filled by `memory_alloc` and consumed by `memory_free`. This way you can double-check if what has been passed to `memory_free` is coherent.
- The linked-list might be time-consuming: as a compromise you can just store the addresses of the beginning and the end of your memory pool and just ensure that pointers passed to `memory_free` are in the correct bound. Its far less precise and sure but faster.

Comment: The trouble is, when using linked lists within an allocator, you still have to allocate each of the nodes. I would suggest a linked list of blocks, where each block contains some constant number of pointers.

Comment: It seems like he already dismissed O(N) solutions in his question as being too inefficient -- he doesn't want to scan a list.

Comment: There are also skip lists which are `O(log N)`. Also, as I already said, a bitvector can speed up the lookup by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Exactly, I've been told by my teacher, that there is better solution. What I don't know whether that solutions is possible with my current memory management.